# PHP/MYSQL SEARCH QUERY RETURNS ERROR: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, search

please I am totally new to mysql, my problem is:

I have a table called 'cong' which has the following columns(id, sort_code, pin, name, state, lga, zip, address, min, min_photo, sec, min_phone, sec_phone) which contains all congregations.

The columns (state, lga) contains the id from the tables 'states' and 'local_govt'.

The 'states' table has the following columns (id, country_id, name), and the 'local_govt' table has the following columns (id, country_id, state_id, name).

I want to carry out a search on the 'cong' table which should search through the 'state' and 'local_govt' tables for matches, below is the search function I wrote:

```
      <?php
      function find_cong($term) {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM cong";
      $query .= " WHERE state rLIKE
      (SELECT id FROM states WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";
      $query .= " OR lga rLIKE
      (SELECT id FROM local_govt WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";
      $query .= " OR upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(address) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(sort_code) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(pin) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(zip) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(min) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(sec) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(min_phone) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $query .= " OR upper(sec_phone) rLIKE '{$term}'";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      confirm_query($result);
      return $result;
      }

      function confirm_query($query) {
          if (!$query) {
             die("Database query failed : " . mysql_error());
          }
      }

      ?>
```

The problem now is that, it searches some terms and comes up with accurate results, but for some specific terms like local_govt and state names it pops an error:
(Database query failed : Subquery returns more than 1 row)

Please I need your help as I don't have any idea how to write the code better than that.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the SQL you're generating to the question?

Comment: what does your query statement look like ?

Comment: The error message says it all - you're using a subquery in a context where it must be return a single value/row, but the subquery is returning multiple rows. e.g. `where x = (select ...)` is one of those cases.

Comment: @andrewsi It was in the code all along, it was just hidden.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the hidden search query

Comment: @ Marc B, so please what do you think i should do? considering the structure of my tables as stated, how do you think i should write the code so that when someone searches for something like "Nigeria" it will display all congregations in Nigeria

Comment: Please note that the 'state' and 'local_govt' columns only contain ID values of the respective state and local governments, (I mean it's related to the tables 'states', and 'local_govt')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have subequeries in the `states` and `local_govt` portions of the WHERE statement. Presumably there are rows for a given value of `$term` where those queries will return a resultset of more than one row. Because you are using `rLIKE`, which expects to evaluate against one value (rather than multiple), the overall query will error out.

Instead, refactor as follows:

```
$query .= " WHERE state IN (SELECT id FROM states WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";
$query .= " OR lga IN (SELECT id FROM local_govt WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";
```

this will account for that contingency.

Please note that the query as written is unlikely to be very performant. Since you are scanning many different columns, it would be best to try not to use regex here, because the optimizer won't be able to leverage indices. Ideally, reduce it to a constant, so that you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM cong WHERE $term IN (upper(name), upper(address)...)
```

but that may not be possible given your requirements. If that's the case, I would probably look at the design of your program and try to split the query into a lookup against one column at most from the application side, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM cong WHERE $term rLIKE upper(NAME)
```

Comment: I tried followed your instructions and it worked well for me, thanks so much. You said it is not very efficient to do it this way, please tell me a more efficient way to write the query. Forgive my ignorance please.

Comment: Added a few suggestions for refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

There error is here:

```
$query .= " WHERE state rLIKE
      (SELECT id FROM states WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";
      $query .= " OR lga rLIKE
      (SELECT id FROM local_govt WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";
```

`rlike` is a regex, but in the end boils down to a straight comparison of values. Your subqueries are returning multiple rows, so in a re-writen fashion, your query would be something more like:

```
WHERE state = a,b,c,...
 OR lga  = z,y,x,...
```

You're trying to do an equality test against multiple values, which is confusing the database. Equality tests are for SINGLE values, e.g. `a=b`, not `a=b,c`.

Comment: thanks so much for the response, but to be honest I don't really understand how you say I should write it. Please do mean i should do something like this:       $query .= " WHERE state =
      (SELECT id FROM states WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";
      $query .= " OR lga =
      (SELECT id FROM local_govt WHERE upper(name) rLIKE '{$term}')";

Comment: doesn't matter how you rewrite, as long as your subqueries only return a SINGLE row+value.

Comment: I tried followed your instructions and it worked well for me, thanks so much. You said it is not very efficient to do it this way, please tell me a more efficient way to write the query. Forgive my ignorance please.